# Confusion regarding the unit step and unit impulse

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, step-function

So I understand that the unit impulse function is the "derivative" of the unit-step, but why is it that unit impulse functions are used to begin with?

My differential equations textbook describes it in a physical sense as impulse functions before more useful to describe voltages/forces of large magnitudes that act over short time intervals, but what makes unit impulse more useful in modeling instantaneous forces?

note: I have justed learned unit-step and unit-impulse functions and am having trouble differentiating between what both do?

Comment: They are popular because in second order equations a Dirac delta on the forcing side can be used to force a sudden jump in the solution value. It would much more wordy to describe such behavior with other means. In the standard situation where the solution is zero for negative times one can implement non-zero initial conditions at zero with delta and unit jump terms.

Comment: But I thought this is also what the Unit Step function does? Is there not a sudden "jump," starting the function?

Comment: I might be slightly confusing something, $y''(x)=\delta(x)$ has $y(x)=\max(0,x)$ as solution, one would need $\delta'$ to get a jump in the value. Note that this is for the forcing side, without making any modifications to the dependent function. A more serious place for the use of $\delta$ is in the definition of the Green's function, where it is used that the Dirac-Delta is the unit of convolution, $\delta*f=f$.